# ANTLR Exception - "Unable to translate Unicode character \uDCAF at index 111 to specified code page."

Tags: .net, iis-7, unicode, antlr, antlr3

Calling all ANTLR experts!

I have a .NET assembly hosted in an IIS website that employs ANTLR to do natural language query processing, search-engine style.  For instance, if a user types:

cheese and crackers and not chips

It builds the following statement:

AND(AND("cheese", "crackers"), NOT("chips"))

We then fire that statement off to our content store and serve up some content to the user.  99.9% of the time everything works great.  However, every once in a while something goes haywire with ANTLR and the IIS-hosted site that does this processing gets stuck in some sort of error state and throws errors non-stop until we do an IISReset / AppPool recycle.  After the recycle, the errors cease immediately.

I'm capturing the stack trace of these errors, which I've included (sanitized, per company policy) below:

```
System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDCAF at index 111 to specified code page.
 at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
 at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)
 at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(Char* chars, Int32 charCount, Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)
 at System.Text.EncoderNLS.GetBytes(Char* chars, Int32 charCount, Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Boolean flush)
 at System.Text.EncoderNLS.GetBytes(Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex, Int32 charCount, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Boolean flush)
 at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
 at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
 at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String value)
 at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String value)
 at Antlr.Runtime.BaseRecognizer.EmitErrorMessage(String msg)
 at Service123.Parser.atomicExpression() in Parser.cs:line 927
 at Service123.Parser.notExpression() in Parser.cs:line 657
 at Service123.Parser.orExpression() in Parser.cs:line 516
 at Service123.Parser.andnotExpression() in Parser.cs:line 416
 at Service123.Parser.andExpression() in Parser.cs:line 234
 at Service123.Parser.startExpression() in Parser.cs:line 167
 at Service123.Processor.ProcessQuery(String queryString) in Processor.cs:line 34
 at Service123.Search.ProcessQueryString(String query) in Search.cs:line 1017
```

Below is a (sanitized again, per company policy) copy of my grammar file:

```
grammar Parser;

options { language = CSharp2; output = AST; }

tokens { IMPLICIT_AND; }

@lexer::namespace { Service123.Parser }
@parser::namespace { Service123.Parser }

L_PARENTHESIS : '(';
R_PARENTHESIS : ')';

AND    : ('A'|'a')('N'|'n')('D'|'d');
OR     : ('O'|'o')('R'|'r');
ANDNOT : ('A'|'a')('N'|'n')('D'|'d')('N'|'n')('O'|'o')('T'|'t');
NOT    : ('N'|'n')('O'|'o')('T'|'t');

fragment LETTER        : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
fragment NUMBER        : ('0'..'9');
fragment SYMBOL_1      : ('+'|'-'|'_'|'|'|'~'|'&'|'`'|'='|'['|']'|'{'|'}');
fragment SYMBOL_2      : ('!'|'@'|'#'|'$'|'%'|'^'|'*'|','|'.'|'/'|':'|';'|'<'|'>'|'?'|'\''|'\\');
fragment SYMBOL_QUOTE  : ('"');
fragment SPACE         : (' '|'\n'|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C');

WS     : (SPACE) { $channel=HIDDEN; };
PHRASE : (SYMBOL_QUOTE)(LETTER|NUMBER|SYMBOL_1|SYMBOL_2)+((SPACE)+(LETTER|NUMBER|SYMBOL_1|SYMBOL_2)+)+(SYMBOL_QUOTE);
WORD   : (LETTER|NUMBER|SYMBOL_1)+;

startExpression  : andExpression;
andExpression    : (         andnotExpression ->              andnotExpression    )
                   (AND? e = andnotExpression -> ^(IMPLICIT_AND $andExpression $e))*;
andnotExpression : orExpression (ANDNOT^ orExpression)*;
orExpression     : notExpression (OR^ notExpression)*;
notExpression    : (NOT^)? atomicExpression;
atomicExpression : PHRASE | WORD | L_PARENTHESIS! andExpression R_PARENTHESIS!;
```

I'm also logging the query strings that go along with these errors and they appear to be common, run-of-the-mill English search terms.

As to the error, the code point in question is not always \uDCAF but is consistent throughout the error cycle; it's always the same code point until we bounce the service, then when the error crops up again after a week of things working fine it's different.

All of the code points I've been able to record are part of a surrogate pair and not representative of valid glyphs on their own.

I'm an admitted ANTLR novice and don't know enough of its inner workings to diagnose much further than this.  It almost seems to me that there's a singleton in the ANTLR runtime that gets screwed up somehow and renders all further processing useless until we reload the assemblies.  I have no proof of this, however.

If you need more details or clarification, please don't hesitate to ask, because I'm at my wit's end.

Comment: So, you have no specific input that produces this exception? If others cannot (easily) reproduce this, I fear that you're on your own with this...

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have yet to find an input that can produce this behavior on-demand.  Between our .NET-level logging and the IIS logs I can pinpoint the moment the errors start occurring, but the first few requests after the first error, as well as the previous dozen before it, all execute just fine on a local instance of the service and on the production service itself after we’ve bounced it.

My hope was somebody out in the world would have an “ah ha” moment having encountered something similar before.  Perhaps too much to hope for, but all my usual debugging avenues have been exhausted.

Comment: If there's no answers/hints here on SO, I recommend you post your question on the [ANTLR's mailing list](http://www.antlr.org/mailman/listinfo/antlr-interest) as well.